# iOS Swift: Create multi-dimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift

I'm trying to sort this array:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
```

into a multi-dimensional array. Something like this:

```
[Result]
  [Small]
    [1,1]
    [2,2]
    [3,3]
  [Big]
    [4,4]
    [5,5]
    [6,6]
```

Here is my first attempt (copy and paste into Playgrounds for fun)

```
import UIKit

var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]
var result = [[[Int]]]()

var big = [[Int]]()
var small = [[Int]]()

for number in numbers {
    var dups = [Int]()

    for number in dups {
        if !contains(dups, number) {
            dups.append(number)
        }
    }

    if number > 3 {
        big.append(dups)
    } else {
        small.append(dups)
    }
}

result.append(big)
result.append(small)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure I understand the 'problem' correctly. But should you be resetting the `big`, `small` and `dups` array for every number you are iterating over? It seems to me that the `dups` array is empty for every number.

Comment: I think you're right. I updated my code, although it's still not working.

Comment: You are still resetting your dups collection for each number you iterate over. Is that correct?